# I'm needing some guidance on using OpenAPI (Swagger) with Drupal

Tags: drupal, swagger, openapi

I am new to Drupal but need to implement the OpenAPI (formally Swagger) to have it describe endpoints of the Drupal RESTful API. `drupal/openapi` has been installed with Composer but I can't find out how to load it in the browser as I can't find what the URL should be.

Beyond that I was hoping to have it automatically generate all the endpoints available but not sure if that's possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only doc I can find for this project is: https://www.drupal.org/project/openapi . I think the project may have been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the url is `http://example.com//openapi/jsonapi?_format=json`. I'm still interested to hear anything someone wants to add.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install other module openapi ui to see the documentation in browser. After installing this module you can login via drupal admin and check the output here. http://example.com/admin/config/services/openapi/swagger/rest.